# AWS - Cloud formation RDS resource creation error - DBInstance did not stabilize

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I see an error in AWS cloud formation when I create a mssql RDS via CFT.

The stack hungs in "CREATE IN PROGRESS" phase, but the RDS was successfully created  and it was in "AVAILABLE" status.

But after sometime like 5 to 6 hours later, the stack gets rolled back deleting the RDS saying "The DBInstance did not stabilize".

Answer (score 4):

From AWS Documentation:
Operations for these(which includes RDS) resources might take longer than the default timeout period. The timeout period depends on the **resource and credentials that you use**. To extend the timeout period, specify a service role when you perform the stack operation. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-resource-did-not-stabilize